# add class name in different li by pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have different `li` and I want to **add class name in first and 2nd item of li** in `JavaScript`.

This is what I tried but could succeed :(

```html
<ul>
        <li>lorem1</li>
        <li>lorem2</li>
        <li>lorem3</li>
        <li>lorem4</li>
        <li>lorem5</li>
        <li>lorem6</li>
        <li>lorem7</li>
        <li>lorem8</li>
        <li>lorem9</li>
    </ul>
```

```js
addClass();

        function addClass() {
            const list = document.querySelectorAll("li");

            list.forEach(function (task) {
                if (task === list.lastChild) {
                    list.className = "test";
                }
                if (task === list.nthChild(2)) {
                    list.className = "test2";
                }
            })
        }
```

```css
.test {
            color: red;
        }

        .test2 {
            color: blue;
        }
```

i want your help

Comment: The fist `<li>` is `"li:nth-child(1)"` - you could `.querySelector()` for that specifically instead of doing a loop.

Comment: Is it just the first and second items, or is it *every* second item? Also, you can easily do this in CSS without Javascript if the only reason you are doing this is for styling?

Comment: why not use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibbling` methods that every DOMelement provides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check with the index and add the classes accordingly. Also instead of `className` use `classList`. And if you know you just want to add classes for 1st and 2nd elements, there's no need of loop as well. Simply you can use `list[0]` and `list[1]`. But for simplicity I didn't remove the loop so that it'll be easy for you to compare with your way of implementation

```js
addClass();

function addClass() {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('li');

  list.forEach(function(task, index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      task.classList.add('test');
    } else if (index === 1) {
      task.classList.add('test2');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}

.test2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem1</li>
  <li>lorem2</li>
  <li>lorem3</li>
  <li>lorem4</li>
  <li>lorem5</li>
  <li>lorem6</li>
  <li>lorem7</li>
  <li>lorem8</li>
  <li>lorem9</li>
</ul>
```

Below is yet another way of fetching the element and updating the class using `document.querySelector('li:nth-of-type()')` for a single element.

```js
addClass();

function addClass() {
  const firstLi = document.querySelector('li:nth-of-type(1)');
  firstLi.classList.add('test');

  const secondLi = document.querySelector('li:nth-of-type(2)');
  secondLi.classList.add('test2');
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}

.test2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem1</li>
  <li>lorem2</li>
  <li>lorem3</li>
  <li>lorem4</li>
  <li>lorem5</li>
  <li>lorem6</li>
  <li>lorem7</li>
  <li>lorem8</li>
  <li>lorem9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop for that. Use the following JS:

```
addClass();

function addClass() {

  const list = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  
  list[0].classList.add("test");
  list[1].classList.add("test2");
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/jdk8v4y3/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibbling`, like this:

```js
function addClass() 
{
    const list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.firstElementChild.classList.add("test");
    list.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling.classList.add("test2");
}

addClass(); // Call the class
```

```css
.test {
  color: green;
}

.test2{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>lorem1</li>
    <li>lorem2</li>
    <li>lorem3</li>
    <li>lorem4</li>
    <li>lorem5</li>
    <li>lorem6</li>
    <li>lorem7</li>
    <li>lorem8</li>
    <li>lorem9</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
const addClass = () => {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  els[0].className = "test";
  els[1].className = "test2";
}

addClass();
```

Note that this will overwrite existing classes.

```js
const addClass = () => {
  const els = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  els[0].className = "test";
  els[1].className = "test2";
}

addClass();
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}

.test2 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem1</li>
  <li>lorem2</li>
  <li>lorem3</li>
  <li>lorem4</li>
  <li>lorem5</li>
  <li>lorem6</li>
  <li>lorem7</li>
  <li>lorem8</li>
  <li>lorem9</li>
</ul>
```